# How to get First and Last for every month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to Add First for 1 to 10 dates for a month and Add Last for 20 to 30 days of month.

```
DECLARE @Today DATE = '2016-11-05'

Select  CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),datepart (DW, @Today)-1 )+' DAYS of '+ LEFT(DATENAME(month,@Today),3) Comments
```

I'm getting like this

```
Comments
6 DAYS of Nov
```

How to get like this :

```
Comments
First 6 DAYS of Nov
```

if I give date as '2016-11-24'

need output like this

```
     Comments
     Last 4 DAYS of Nov
```

Suggest me the way to proceed

Answer (score 4):

Use a `case` statement:

```
Select (CASE WHEN day(@today) <= 10 THEN 'First '
             WHEN day(@today) >= 20 THEN 'Last '
             ELSE ''
        END) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), datepart(DW, @Today)-1 ) + ' DAYS of ' +
        LEFT(DATENAME(month, @Today), 3) as Comments
```

EDIT:

Oh, now I see the original query was not right.  So you want something more like this:

```
Select (CASE WHEN day(@today) <= 10 THEN 'First ' + DATENAME(day, @today) + ' DAYS of ' + LEFT(DATENAME(month, @Today), 3)
             WHEN day(@today) >= 20 AND MONTH(@Today) IN (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12) THEN 'Last ' + CAST(31 - day(@today) as varchar(255))
             WHEN day(@today) >= 20 AND MONTH(@Today) IN (4, 6, 9, 11) THEN 'Last ' + CAST(30 - day(@today) as varchar(255))
             WHEN day(@today) >= 20 AND MONTH(@Today) IN (2) AND YEAR(@Today) % 4 = 0 THEN 'Last ' + CAST(29 - day(@today) as varchar(255))
             WHEN day(@today) >= 20 AND MONTH(@Today) IN (2) AND YEAR(@Today) % 4 <> 0 THEN 'Last ' + CAST(29 - day(@today) as varchar(255))
             ELSE CAST(day(@today) as varchar(255))
        END)  + ' DAYS of ' + LEFT(DATENAME(month, @Today), 3) as Comments
```

Comment: If I give  2016-11-24 it should give Last 4 DAYS of Nov but it is giving First 4 DAYS of Nov

Comment: when I give today's date or 11 to 20 dates it is giving wrong results like if I give 12/11/2016 it is giving 126 DAYS of Nov

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Today DATE = '2016-11-09'

Select (CASE WHEN day(@today) <= 10 THEN 'First ' + DATENAME(day, @today)
             WHEN day(@today) >= 20 THEN 'Last ' + CAST(DAY(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@Today)+1,0))) - day(@today) as varchar(255))
             ELSE CAST(day(@today) as varchar(255) )
        END)  + ' DAYS of ' + LEFT(DATENAME(month, @Today), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server 2012 developers can now use new SQL date function EOMonth() for calculating the last date of the month where a given date is in.

Here is my query

```
--DECLARE @Today DATE = '2016-11-05'
DECLARE @Today DATE = '2016-11-24'

SELECT
 case when DATEPART(dd,@Today) <= 10 then
 'First ' + convert(varchar(2), DATEPART(dd,@Today)) + ' of ' + DATENAME(mm,@Today)
 else
 'Last ' + convert(varchar(2), DATEDIFF(dd, @Today, EOMONTH (@Today))) + ' of ' + DATENAME(mm,@Today)
 end
```

The [SQL EOMonth() function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/end-of-month-eomonth-function-in-sql-server-2012.aspx) makes it easier to calculate the last date of a month, and also indirectly calculating the first date of next month or previous month

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT case when DATEPART(dd,@Today) <= 10 then
 'First ' + convert(varchar(2), DATEPART(dd,@Today)) + ' DAYS of ' + DATENAME(mm,@Today) 
WHEN DATEPART(dd,@Today) >= 20 then  'Last ' + convert(varchar(2),
DATEDIFF(dd, @Today, EOMONTH (@Today))) + ' DAYS of ' + DATENAME(mm,@Today) 
ELSE @Today END
```